# Conditional width and ellipsis not working on styled component - React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

My component has a `width` that should change its `size` depending on a `prop` I'm sending to it.

```
export const PixCodeBox = styled(Box)`
  ${isCopied => css`
    width: ${isCopied ? '170px' : '189px'};
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  `}
`;
```

Not only is the conditional width not working, but the `text-overflow: ellipsis` is also not working. Does someone know what is wrong with my code? The variable "isCopied" is a boolean that changes its state when I press a button.

Comment: Can you add more context to your issue? What's the `Box` component style?

Comment: It is the vanilla Box from @chakra-ui/react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approuch like describe in styled-components [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#style-objects) without **css** imports from `@emotion/styled`:

```js
export const PixCodeBox = styled(Box)(({ isCopied }) => ({
  width: isCopied ? "170px" : "189px",
  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  overflow: "hidden",
  textOverflow: "ellipsis"
}));
```

or use a condition inside the width property:

```js
export const PixCodeBox2 = styled(Box)`
  width: ${({ isCopied }) => (isCopied ? "170px" : "189px")};
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
`;
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]